# Needing to get a list of strings into a webservice

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am creating a web service via asp.net.  I want to pull as a list the Address's of the Fuel Stops as shown below unfortunately what I am getting is the string name of address's as shown below from the xml...

Unfortunately when I do run this I get a xml file filled with

```
-<FuelStop> 
    <Physical_Address_Street>Physical_Address_Street</Physical_Address_Street>                   
    <Physical_Address_Local>Physical_Address_Local</Physical_Address_Local> 
    <Physical_Address_State>Physical_Address_State</Physical_Address_State>           
    <Physical_Address_Zip>Physical_Address_Zip</Physical_Address_Zip> 
    <Phone_Number>Phone_Number</Phone_Number> 
</FuelStop>
```

Versus getting the address info that is populated in the database.

Below is my code.

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://watersports.com 8010/",     Description:="Holds Fuel Stop and Shelter information", Name:="ShelterandFuelService")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetAddresses(ByVal skip As Integer, ByVal take As Integer) As FuelStop()

    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection
    Dim resultList = New List(Of FuelStop)()


    Try

        sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=google.watersports.com;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=30;User ID=****;Password=******"
                   Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT @Physical_Address_Street, @Physical_Address_Local, @Physical_Address_State, @Physical_Address_Zip, @Phone_Number FROM Gas_Stations WHERE Location_Type = 1")
        command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_Street", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_Street"
        command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_Local", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_Local"
        command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_State", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_State"
        command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_Zip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_Zip"
        command.Parameters.Add("@Phone_Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Phone_Number"

        command.Connection = sqlCon
        sqlCon.Open()
        'command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Dim fuelStop = New FuelStop()
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Street = reader.GetString(0)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Local = reader.GetString(1)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_State = reader.GetString(2)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Zip = reader.GetString(3)
                fuelStop.Phone_Number = reader.GetString(4)

                resultList.Add(fuelStop)


            End While
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        sqlCon.Close()
    Finally
        sqlCon.Close()

    End Try
    Return resultList.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray()
```

Based on the Sql Command below I will return possibly a few hundred address's how do I incorporparate this into my vb.net logic to return the list of address's?

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Physical_Address_Street, Physical_Address_Local, Physical_Address_State, Physical_Address_Zip, Phone_Number FROM Gas_Stations WHERE Location_Type = 1")
```

And here is my Fuel stop class

```
Public Class FuelStop

    Property Physical_Address_Street As String

    Property Physical_Address_Local As String

    Property Physical_Address_State As String

    Property Physical_Address_Zip As String

    Property Phone_Number As String

End Class
```

Comment: Where do you get the XML file? If it is inside the Android App, I would suggest opening a new question because that is separate from how to write the web service. I would guess that inside of Android the runtime libraries have utilities for deserializing XML into an object that you can then use within the application.

Comment: Oh the xml is generated by the webservice by clicking on the GetAddress button on the webpage.

Comment: I was expecting a list of actual address's that are inside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should give you what you are looking for. I am not sure if WebMethods can return custom objects like the Address object below. If it can not do that then you could convert the return type to String() and turn each Address object into a json object.

If I was doing this from scratch, I would just return a single JSON array that contained a list of Address objects.

Also, I have included in this method signature a skip and take parameter, as you mentioned in your comment, the web service sql query is unbounded so it could return hundreds of addresses. By using the skip and take you can limit how many are returned at once and can page through them from the client. To reduce the size of the sql query you could pass the skip and take parameters into the sql query to reduce the number of rows returned, which would improve performance as the number of addresses grows.

There are additional safety checks you can include in the below code to prevent errors but this can get you moving.

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Function GetAddresses(skip As Integer, take As Integer) As Address()
    Dim resultList = New List(Of Address)()
    Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection()
            sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=google.watersports.com;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=30;User ID=****;Password=******"
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Physical_Address_Street, Physical_Address_Local, Physical_Address_State, Physical_Address_Zip, Phone_Number FROM Gas_Stations WHERE Location_Type = 1")

            sqlCon.Open()
            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim addr = New Address()
                    addr.Physical_Address_Street = reader.GetString(0)
                    addr.Physical_Address_Local = reader.GetString(1)
                    addr.Physical_Address_State = reader.GetString(2)
                    addr.Physical_Address_Zip = reader.GetString(3)
                    addr.Phone_Number = reader.GetString(4)

                    resultList.Add(addr)
                End While
            End Using
    End Using
    Return resultList.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray()
End Function
```

Below is a temp class object that is used above.

```
public class Address
{
    public string Physical_Address_Street { get; set; }
    public string Physical_Address_Local { get; set; }
    public string Physical_Address_State { get; set; }
    public string Physical_Address_Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone_Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is a very detailed response rclement I will try this and respond back.  I do appreciate the detail on this.  And thank you as well.  I'll let you know how this works.

Comment: Ok so I have a question rclement how do I add this public string gets and set?

Comment: And how do I pass in the skip and the take?

Comment: The skip and take would be passed in via the javascript method that is calling the web service. I am not sure what you mean by "add public string get and sets".

Comment: I would be using this for an android app so what would I pass in for this?  And as far as the Get and Set  I meant the Public Address class what am I supposed to do there?

Comment: The address class is just a DTO for transporting the data in an organized manner. I don't have any experience with Android programming, passing parameters in a Android web service call is probably answered somewhere else on the SO already.

Comment: So when I do this I get -<FuelStop> <Physical_Address_Street>Physical_Address_Street</Physical_Address_Street> <Physical_Address_Local>Physical_Address_Local</Physical_Address_Local> <Physical_Address_State>Physical_Address_State</Physical_Address_State> <Physical_Address_Zip>Physical_Address_Zip</Physical_Address_Zip> <Phone_Number>Phone_Number</Phone_Number> </FuelStop>

Comment: I am going to change my question and show the result in the question above.

Comment: Ok take a look at what I added.

Comment: So unfortunately I get a list of strings but the name of the colums not what is in the database.

Comment: So rclement any help on this?

Comment: When I run the above code, I get a list of addresses with the data for each address in it. I don't know why you are not getting the same. I would suggest another pair of eyes from a Dev team member to review your code and look for any errors.