# I need to return a list of Adresses from a asp.net webservice to a Android app

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, sql-server-2008

I am creating a webservice on asp.net using vb. This webservice will get addresses from a SQL Server 2008 database and return to the Android platform. So far all I have is the code to get the database connection and open it.  How can I get this to return the list of all addresses in the database?  What can I do to get the webservice to return all the entries in the specified database?

```vb
Public Class Service1 Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetAddresses() As FuelStop()
        Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection
        Dim resultList = New List(Of FuelStop)()
        Try
            sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=google.watersports.com;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=30;User ID=****;Password=******"
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT @Physical_Address_Street, @Physical_Address_Local, @Physical_Address_State, @Physical_Address_Zip, @Phone_Number FROM Gas_Stations WHERE Location_Type = 1")
            command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_Street", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_Street"
            command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_Local", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_Local"
            command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_State", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_State"
            command.Parameters.Add("@Physical_Address_Zip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Physical_Address_Zip"
            command.Parameters.Add("@Phone_Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Phone_Number"
            command.Connection = sqlCon
            sqlCon.Open()
```

And as far as the Fuel Stop class All I have is

```vb
Public Class FuelStop
    Property Physical_Address_Street As String
    Property Physical_Address_Local As String
    Property Physical_Address_State As String
    Property Physical_Address_Zip As String
    Property Phone_Number As String
End Class
```

Comment: How is this different from [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048355/needing-to-get-a-list-of-strings-into-a-webservice?noredirect=1#comment22942651_16048355)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm I think you're over complicating things try this:

```
Public Function GetAddresses() As FuelStop()
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection
    Dim resultList = New List(Of FuelStop)()
    Try
        sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=google.watersports.com;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=30;User ID=****;Password=******"
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Physical_Address_Street, Physical_Address_Local, Physical_Address_State, Physical_Address_Zip, Phone_Number FROM Gas_Stations WHERE Location_Type = 1")
        command.Connection = sqlCon
        sqlCon.Open()
```